# Material skin in child form won't load

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public HomeBase()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var SkinManager = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
    SkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);

    SkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
    SkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.DeepOrange800, Primary.Brown900, Primary.DeepOrange500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
}

private void materialRaisedButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form Banking = new Form();
            
    Banking.ShowDialog();
}
```

This code is the main form and I am trying to open form called banking which does open however the material skin settings don't show up

banking public banking()

```
InitializeComponent();

var SkinManager = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
SkinManager.AddFormToManage(Form);

SkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;

SkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.DeepOrange800, Primary.Brown900, Primary.DeepOrange500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
```

Any advice would be helpful

I have tried passing the main form controls to the child form with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Would like to see more of your code, specifically the Program.cs class, but in any case, be sure to have
Application.EnableVisualStyles();

in your Main() method.